# How to get the top 5 most used RGB colors from an image?

Tags: c#

I need a direction to perform this. I am iterating through all the pixels and getting the value through `GetPixel()` method. What should I do next?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What approaches have you considered? Stack Overflow is not a place that will do your thinking or work for you - please show us the efforts you have gone through and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a helper method to get all pixels:

```
public static IEnumerable<Color> GetPixels(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
        {
            Color pixel = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
            yield return pixel;
        }
    }
}
```

If you just need the colors (without the counters):

```
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(@"..."))
{
    var mostUsedColors =
        GetPixels(bitmap)
            .GroupBy(color => color)
            .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
            .Select(grp => grp.Key)
            .Take(5);
    foreach (var color in mostUsedColors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Color {0}", color);
    }
}
```

By the way, here is the selection of top 5 most used colors with the counters:

```
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(@"..."))
{
    var colorsWithCount =
        GetPixels(bitmap)
            .GroupBy(color => color)
            .Select(grp =>
                new
                    {
                        Color = grp.Key,
                        Count = grp.Count()
                    })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
            .Take(5);

    foreach (var colorWithCount in colorsWithCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Color {0}, count: {1}",
            colorWithCount.Color, colorWithCount.Count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate them in a `Dictionary<Color, int>` where you keep the count for each color. After you have iterated over all of them, extract the top 5 ordered by Value (count).

A less well performing but simpler solution is this:

```
(from c in allColors
group c by c into g
order by g.Count() descending
select g.Key).Take(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will not write the code for you, but give a general description of what you need:

1. A data structure that holds each color and the number of times it appears
2. For each pixel, if the color exists in your data structure, increment the number
   2.a if the color does not exist, add it with a count of 1
3. Once you have gone through all pixels, sort the structure by the count and get the top 5

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<Color, int> dictColors = new Dictionary<Color, int>();
```

then when you are iterating through each pixel , do this

```
Color color =GetPixel(x,y);
if(!dictColors.Contains(color) )
{
dictColors.Add(color,0);
}
else
{
dictColors[color]++;
}

then take first five:
 var top5 = dictColors.Take(5);
```